# Detect click on KML region in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, kml

I'm displaying a KML overlay on a map:

var k1 = new GGeoXml(url);
map.addOverlay( k1 );

I want to detect when that region has been clicked. This does not work:

GEvent.addListener(k1, 'click', function () { alert('you clicked k1'); });

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using the V2 Maps API.

Checking through the documentation, the [GGeoXml](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GGeoXml) class doesn't raise a 'click' event, and the interface it implements, [GOverlay](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GOverlay) doesn't expose that event either.  So, although you're theoretically binding to that event, it will never be triggered.

You're binding a listener to an event that doesn't exist- the [GOverlay](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GOverlay) doesn't raise any events.

On a quick view, only the [GMap2](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GMap2) raises mouse events (perhaps other classes too).  Have you tried adding a listener to this and then checking the source object when the event fires?

```
  var k1 = new GGeoXml(url);
  map.addOverlay(k1);
  GEvent.addListener(map, 'click', callback);

  function (overlay, latlng) callback
  {
    if (overlay == k1) alert('you clicked on k1');
  }
```

(See [EventListener docs](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/events.html#Event_Listeners))

The Google Maps APIs aren't very flexible; bear in mind that KML overlays are even less flexible, what do you want to do when you've clicked on the overlay?